# Low accuracy of LSTM model tensorflow

Tags: python, machine-learning, neural-network, tensorflow

I am trying to learn LSTM model for sentiment analysis using Tensorflow, I have gone through the [LSTM model](http://colah.github.io/posts/2015-08-Understanding-LSTMs/).

Following code **(create_sentiment_featuresets.py)** generates the lexicon from *5000 positive sentences and 5000 negative sentences*.

```
import nltk
from nltk.tokenize import word_tokenize
import numpy as np
import random
from collections import Counter
from nltk.stem import WordNetLemmatizer

lemmatizer = WordNetLemmatizer()

def create_lexicon(pos, neg):
    lexicon = []
    with open(pos, 'r') as f:
        contents = f.readlines()
        for l in contents[:len(contents)]:
            l= l.decode('utf-8')
            all_words = word_tokenize(l)
            lexicon += list(all_words)
    f.close()

    with open(neg, 'r') as f:
        contents = f.readlines()    
        for l in contents[:len(contents)]:
            l= l.decode('utf-8')
            all_words = word_tokenize(l)
            lexicon += list(all_words)
    f.close()

    lexicon = [lemmatizer.lemmatize(i) for i in lexicon]
    w_counts = Counter(lexicon)
    l2 = []
    for w in w_counts:
        if 1000 > w_counts[w] > 50:
            l2.append(w)
    print("Lexicon length create_lexicon: ",len(lexicon))
    return l2

def sample_handling(sample, lexicon, classification):
    featureset = []
    print("Lexicon length Sample handling: ",len(lexicon))
    with open(sample, 'r') as f:
        contents = f.readlines()
        for l in contents[:len(contents)]:
            l= l.decode('utf-8')
            current_words = word_tokenize(l.lower())
            current_words= [lemmatizer.lemmatize(i) for i in current_words]
            features = np.zeros(len(lexicon))
            for word in current_words:
                if word.lower() in lexicon:
                    index_value = lexicon.index(word.lower())
                    features[index_value] +=1
            features = list(features)
            featureset.append([features, classification])
    f.close()
    print("Feature SET------")
    print(len(featureset))
    return featureset

def create_feature_sets_and_labels(pos, neg, test_size = 0.1):
    global m_lexicon
    m_lexicon = create_lexicon(pos, neg)
    features = []
    features += sample_handling(pos, m_lexicon, [1,0])
    features += sample_handling(neg, m_lexicon, [0,1])
    random.shuffle(features)
    features = np.array(features)

    testing_size = int(test_size * len(features))

    train_x = list(features[:,0][:-testing_size])
    train_y = list(features[:,1][:-testing_size])
    test_x = list(features[:,0][-testing_size:])
    test_y = list(features[:,1][-testing_size:])
    return train_x, train_y, test_x, test_y

def get_lexicon():
    global m_lexicon
    return m_lexicon
```

The following code **(sentiment_analysis.py)** is for *sentiment analysis using simple neural network model* and is working fine

```
from create_sentiment_featuresets import create_feature_sets_and_labels
from create_sentiment_featuresets import get_lexicon
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np
# extras for testing
from nltk.tokenize import word_tokenize 
from nltk.stem import WordNetLemmatizer
lemmatizer = WordNetLemmatizer()
#- end extras

train_x, train_y, test_x, test_y = create_feature_sets_and_labels('pos.txt', 'neg.txt')


# pt A-------------

n_nodes_hl1 = 1500
n_nodes_hl2 = 1500
n_nodes_hl3 = 1500

n_classes = 2
batch_size = 100
hm_epochs = 10

x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32)
y = tf.placeholder(tf.float32)

hidden_1_layer = {'f_fum': n_nodes_hl1,
                'weight': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([len(train_x[0]), n_nodes_hl1])),
                'bias': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([n_nodes_hl1]))}
hidden_2_layer = {'f_fum': n_nodes_hl2,
                'weight': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([n_nodes_hl1, n_nodes_hl2])),
                'bias': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([n_nodes_hl2]))}
hidden_3_layer = {'f_fum': n_nodes_hl3,
                'weight': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([n_nodes_hl2, n_nodes_hl3])),
                'bias': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([n_nodes_hl3]))}
output_layer = {'f_fum': None,
                'weight': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([n_nodes_hl3, n_classes])),
                'bias': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([n_classes]))}


def nueral_network_model(data):
    l1 = tf.add(tf.matmul(data, hidden_1_layer['weight']), hidden_1_layer['bias'])
    l1 = tf.nn.relu(l1)
    l2 = tf.add(tf.matmul(l1, hidden_2_layer['weight']), hidden_2_layer['bias'])
    l2 = tf.nn.relu(l2)
    l3 = tf.add(tf.matmul(l2, hidden_3_layer['weight']), hidden_3_layer['bias'])
    l3 = tf.nn.relu(l3)
    output = tf.matmul(l3, output_layer['weight']) + output_layer['bias']
    return output

# pt B--------------

def train_neural_network(x):
    prediction = nueral_network_model(x)
    cost = tf.reduce_mean( tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(logits= prediction, labels= y))
    optimizer = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(learning_rate= 0.001).minimize(cost)

    with tf.Session() as sess:
        sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
        for epoch in range(hm_epochs):
            epoch_loss = 0
            i = 0
            while i < len(train_x):
                start = i
                end = i+ batch_size
                batch_x = np.array(train_x[start: end])
                batch_y = np.array(train_y[start: end])
                _, c = sess.run([optimizer, cost], feed_dict= {x: batch_x, y: batch_y})
                epoch_loss += c
                i+= batch_size
            print('Epoch', epoch+ 1, 'completed out of ', hm_epochs, 'loss:', epoch_loss)

        correct= tf.equal(tf.argmax(prediction, 1), tf.argmax(y, 1))
        accuracy = tf.reduce_mean(tf.cast(correct, 'float'))
        print('Accuracy:', accuracy.eval({x:test_x, y:test_y}))

        # testing --------------
        m_lexicon= get_lexicon()
        print('Lexicon length: ',len(m_lexicon))        
        input_data= "David likes to go out with Kary"       
        current_words= word_tokenize(input_data.lower())
        current_words = [lemmatizer.lemmatize(i) for i in current_words]
        features = np.zeros(len(m_lexicon))
        for word in current_words:
            if word.lower() in m_lexicon:
                index_value = m_lexicon.index(word.lower())
                features[index_value] +=1

        features = np.array(list(features)).reshape(1,-1)
        print('features length: ',len(features))
        result = sess.run(tf.argmax(prediction.eval(feed_dict={x:features}), 1))
        print(prediction.eval(feed_dict={x:features}))
        if result[0] == 0:
            print('Positive: ', input_data)
        elif result[0] == 1:
            print('Negative: ', input_data)

train_neural_network(x)
```

**I have modified the above (sentiment_analysis.py) for LSTM model**
after reading the [RNN w/ LSTM cell example in TensorFlow and Python](https://pythonprogramming.net/rnn-tensorflow-python-machine-learning-tutorial/?completed=/recurrent-neural-network-rnn-lstm-machine-learning-tutorial/) which is for LSTM on *mnist image dataset*:

Some how through many hit and run trails, I was able to get the below running  code **(sentiment_demo_lstm.py)** :

```
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.contrib import rnn
from create_sentiment_featuresets import create_feature_sets_and_labels
from create_sentiment_featuresets import get_lexicon

import numpy as np

# extras for testing
from nltk.tokenize import word_tokenize 
from nltk.stem import WordNetLemmatizer
lemmatizer = WordNetLemmatizer()
#- end extras

train_x, train_y, test_x, test_y = create_feature_sets_and_labels('pos.txt', 'neg.txt')

n_steps= 100
input_vec_size= len(train_x[0])
hm_epochs = 8
n_classes = 2
batch_size = 128
n_hidden = 128

x = tf.placeholder('float', [None, input_vec_size, 1])
y = tf.placeholder('float')

def recurrent_neural_network(x):
    layer = {'weights': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([n_hidden, n_classes])),   # hidden_layer, n_classes
            'biases': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([n_classes]))}

    h_layer = {'weights': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([1, n_hidden])), # hidden_layer, n_classes
            'biases': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([n_hidden], mean = 1.0))}

    x = tf.transpose(x, [1,0,2])
    x = tf.reshape(x, [-1, 1])
    x = tf.split(x, input_vec_size, 0)

    lstm_cell = rnn.BasicLSTMCell(n_hidden, state_is_tuple=True)
    outputs, states = rnn.static_rnn(lstm_cell, x, dtype= tf.float32)
    output = tf.matmul(outputs[-1], layer['weights']) + layer['biases']

    return output

def train_neural_network(x):
    prediction = recurrent_neural_network(x)
    cost = tf.reduce_mean( tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(logits= prediction, labels= y))
    optimizer = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(learning_rate= 0.001).minimize(cost)

    with tf.Session() as sess:
        sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())

        for epoch in range(hm_epochs):
            epoch_loss = 0
            i = 0
            while (i+ batch_size) < len(train_x):
                start = i
                end = i+ batch_size
                batch_x = np.array(train_x[start: end])
                batch_y = np.array(train_y[start: end])
                batch_x = batch_x.reshape(batch_size ,input_vec_size, 1)
                _, c = sess.run([optimizer, cost], feed_dict= {x: batch_x, y: batch_y})
                epoch_loss += c
                i+= batch_size
            print('--------Epoch', epoch+ 1, 'completed out of ', hm_epochs, 'loss:', epoch_loss)

        correct= tf.equal(tf.argmax(prediction, 1), tf.argmax(y, 1))
        accuracy = tf.reduce_mean(tf.cast(correct, 'float'))

        print('Accuracy:', accuracy.eval({x:np.array(test_x).reshape(-1, input_vec_size, 1), y:test_y}))

        # testing --------------
        m_lexicon= get_lexicon()
        print('Lexicon length: ',len(m_lexicon))
        input_data= "Mary does not like pizza"  #"he seems to to be healthy today"  #"David likes to go out with Kary"

        current_words= word_tokenize(input_data.lower())
        current_words = [lemmatizer.lemmatize(i) for i in current_words]
        features = np.zeros(len(m_lexicon))
        for word in current_words:
            if word.lower() in m_lexicon:
                index_value = m_lexicon.index(word.lower())
                features[index_value] +=1
        features = np.array(list(features)).reshape(-1, input_vec_size, 1)
        print('features length: ',len(features))

        result = sess.run(tf.argmax(prediction.eval(feed_dict={x:features}), 1))
        print('RESULT: ', result)
        print(prediction.eval(feed_dict={x:features}))
        if result[0] == 0:
            print('Positive: ', input_data)
        elif result[0] == 1:
            print('Negative: ', input_data)

train_neural_network(x)
```

**Output of**

```
print(train_x[0])
[0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0]

print(train_y[0])
[0, 1]
```

`len(train_x)= 9596`, `len(train_x[0]) = 423`  meaning `train_x` is a list of 9596x423 ?

The above code is running. BUT I am not able to get the accuracy above 50 percent. Its always between 45-50 %

1. **Is there anything wrong in my implementation?**
2. How should I approach to improve the accuracy *apart from collecting larger database*?

I am new in this field, please help.
Thanks.

Comment: Is your dataset available somewhere? Otherwise it might be hard to reproduce the statistics.

Comment: I suggest you visit [Cross Validated](https://stats.stackexchange.com).

Comment: Considering the code does not produce the intended result (a high enough accuracy), the code is not ready for review. On Code Review, we only review code that already works the way it should (producing the output it should). Please take a look at the [help/on-topic].